# Problems in DNS - Domain hosted on Gandi - DNS managed by Route 53

Tags: dns, amazon-route53

Problem - Unable to resolve my domain name theplaybook.rocks

Domain purchased from . - Gandi.net. 
DNS managed via Route 53 Hosted Zone. 
In Route 53 I have added A & AAAA records pointing to a CloudFront distribution. Similarly have created A & AAAA records for www subdomain.
Changed Nameservers in Gandi.net to reflect what is in Route 53.
Did not work for 2 days - still can't access my domain - Note: the cloudfront distributions work on browser. I have also set up alternate domain names in cloudfront to point correctly to my domain.

From here on everything I write are assumptions and what all I tried.

After it was not working I searched a lot on the internet and thought maybe there was an issue with "GLUE" records from https://intodns.com/theplaybook.rocks. So I added GLUE records in Gandi.net since I was told (by some site or the other) that they have to be added at the Registrar. However, after adding GLUE records by getting reverse ip of the aws Nameservers (which may not in itself by right - I don't know) Gandi.net informed that I have to add them to the Nameservers to take effect - which I tried by adding just in Route 53, then just in Gandi.net and then keeping them in both but to no avail.

I really have no clue where all I am going wrong. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The dns resolution is intermittent because you have a Mixed set of Nameservers configured.

```
Current Nameservers:
theplaybook.rocks.  86288   IN  NS  ns-1028.awsdns-00.org.
theplaybook.rocks.  86288   IN  NS  ns1.theplaybook.rocks.
theplaybook.rocks.  86288   IN  NS  ns-1814.awsdns-34.co.uk.
theplaybook.rocks.  86288   IN  NS  ns3.theplaybook.rocks.
theplaybook.rocks.  86288   IN  NS  ns2.theplaybook.rocks.
theplaybook.rocks.  86288   IN  NS  ns-618.awsdns-13.net.
theplaybook.rocks.  86288   IN  NS  ns-213.awsdns-26.com.
theplaybook.rocks.  86288   IN  NS  ns4.theplaybook.rocks.
```

The one of Route53 are correct and gives IP address:

```
dig theplaybook.rocks @ns-1028.awsdns-00.org +short
54.230.71.59
54.230.71.3
54.230.71.55
54.230.71.78
```

The other are not correct and not reachable:

```
>dig theplaybook.rocks @ns1.theplaybook.rocks

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> theplaybook.rocks @ns1.theplaybook.rocks
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

If your DNS server queries to one of ns*.theplaybook.rocks, it will fail.

You need to make sure that you're only using AWS nameservers in Gandi. Remove the other 4.

Comment: Thanks... Ive done that and waiting for the propagation to happen. Although what you suggested was exactly what I had done in the beginning (3 days ago) and tried other stuff when it hadn't worked. I will reply back in some time after the changes take effect.

Comment: some more info if that helps - https://dnschecker.org/#CNAME/theplaybook.rocks - all "Not resolved" while if you check A, AAAA & NS records using the same tool it is "Resolved". Does this say what could be wrong?

Comment: You don't have CNAME record for theplaybook.rocks and you can't have CNAME for the apex domain as per RFC, you're using a feature called Alias record which acts like a A record. in dnscheck you're trying to look for CNAME which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

The problem was entirely of my own making. While developing I had configure localhost against the same domain name by editing etc/hosts file. Just checked on a different laptop on a whim and it is working fine there.

Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Although this was your problem but externally also you have mixed up NS records so you would have seen intermittent problem in resolving if anyone connects to other NS records.

Comment: Still not working... lol... any advice? --> This is also an incorrect statement, when you perform nslookup or dig, it doesn't look at /etc/hosts (although browser and other application does) which suggests that you didn't bother to run the commands or even if you did you dns may have queries to the nonworking NS.

Comment: Yes, James Dean. You are right. Have corrected them too. Thanks a lot for all your replies.

And about etc/hosts file - again you are right (although me being an absolute noob - I was in sales for 15 years before I picked up coding earlier this year) and I hadn't noticed what else I had done.

I had also made a CA and imported into chrome to allow my domain name to be used on the browser locally for testing. Lol! But learning from mistakes is awesome anyway :-). Thanks again.